# Show that if $a_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt(n)} +\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} $then the alternating series formed diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I start ? I actually get the idea that the {$a_{n}$} -> 0 as $n -> infinity$. And $a_{n+1} - a_{n} \le 2(-1)^{n}$. So I dont think I'll be able to use the alternating series 
Theorem . Now how do I proceed ?

Comment: This is not an alternating series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that " the alternating series formed" means that you consider an alternating series with term $a_n$.

If
$$
a_n  = \frac{1}
{{\sqrt n }} + \frac{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{n - 1} }}
{n}
$$
then
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n - 1} a_n }  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left[ {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n - 1} \frac{1}
{{\sqrt n }} + \frac{1}
{n}} \right]} 
$$
Since
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n - 1} \frac{1}
{{\sqrt n }}} 
$$
is convergent by Leibniz while 
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}
{n}} 
$$
is divergent, the alternating series of $a_n$ is divergent

Answer (score 1):

For $n>4:$

$2√n =√4√n < √n√n= n;$

$\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{2√n};$

$\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{√n} =$

$ \frac{1}{√n} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{√n}< \frac{1}{√n}  -\frac{1}{n} \le a_n$.

$\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle{\sum} \frac{1}{√n}$ diverges, hence $\displaystyle{\sum} a_n$ diverges (comparison test ).

Comment: It's very hard to understand whta you wrote. Why not MathJaX?

Comment: DonAntonio. Edited. Hopefully better now. Thanks.